# Visual Studio 2015 Community - can't run any code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I installed VS Community 2015 and ran simple C++ code to check if everything is working, but it didn't succeded. VS crashes and does nothing, but process of ran C++ program has still its process working and I can't stop it in Task Manager. What might be the reason of that?

Comment: I think I'll unfortunately havy to do it :(. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @irqize: Do you use Avast antivirus?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh yeah! It worked! Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHodges: It's not a Microsoft problem, Avast has been causing the same issue for gcc users.

Comment: *the ususal fix is to reinstall windows, reinstall visual studio, reboot, apply updates and reboot again.*  you're doing it very wrong if that is your *usual* fix :]

Comment: it failed to install on my machine 4 times - with no antivirus at all. I'm looking for the stackoverflow article that helped me to finally get it working. It involved lots of registry manipulation and file permission changes.

Comment: @stijn my usual fix is to work on a real working operating system rather than the windows toybox. Occasionally though, I am forced to develop on windows because of misguided customer requirements. These projects invariably take twice as long to develop - all of the extra time is taken in installing software correctly. It saps my will to live...